# Intellij Idea search endpoints with variable path in tool "Endpoints"

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, endpoint

Using Spring framework.
I have path:
@GetMapping("/session/{someId}/example")

In Intellij Idea tool "Endpoints" I write "/session/{someId}/example" - it present.

How to search endpoints in "Endpoints" if I do not know exactly name of variable "{someId}"?

In browsing we see "/session/01/example". I trying regex but it does not work.

"/session/.*/example" and "/session/{}/example" - does not work

Comment: It seems regex search doesn't work properly in Endpoints tool window. Feel free to raise a new issue at JetBrains issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write this and it should match one or more characters:

```
"/session/.+/example"
```

or only for number:

```
/session/\d+/example
```

and the last one. you can easily find your all endpoints and just check manually

```
/session
```

However, check the site regex online [regexOnline](https://regex101.com/) and put there your regex and link what should it match without "" quotes.